# Why does .classname > ul {color:red} make all nested <ul>s red?

Tags: html, css

I do not understand the meaning of the element selector ">". I thought it would style only direct children, but is does not.

#### HTML

```
<div class="infos">
    <ul>
        <li> marmelade</li>
        <li> schokolade</li>
        <li> softeis</li>
        <li> mandeln</li>
        <li>
            <ul>
                <li> marmelade</li>
                <li> schokolade</li>
                <li> softeis</li>
                <li> mandeln</li>
            </ul>
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

#### CSS

```
body {
  color: #0bdede;
}

.infos > ul {
  color: red;
}
```

Why are *both* `<ul>`s in red? [js fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/wrsHt/1/)

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is answered in the manual. Please use Google *before* using Stack Overflow.

Comment: @JohnConde    it does not explain it: http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/sel_element_gt.asp

Comment: You shouldn't be using [w3schools](http://w3fools.com) (and they aren't Google).

Comment: http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-selectors/#descendant-combinators

Comment: @JohnConde: I’ve edited the question so that it gets to the actual point the OP is trying to understand.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Edit:** Ah. Note that the `color` property is inherited. If you make an element red, all its descendants will be red unless they’re set to another colour.

So, to edit your example CSS to get your desired effect:

```
.infos ul {
  color: #0bdede;
}

.infos > ul {
  color: red;
}
```

- http://jsfiddle.net/wrsHt/2/

---

> I thought it would style only direct children, but is does not.

It does. For example:

#### CSS

```
.classname  ul  { color: green; }

.classname > ul { color: red; }
```

#### HTML

```
<div class="classname">
    <ul>
        <li>Direct child list: red</li>
    </ul>

    <div>
        <ul>
            <li>Descendant list, not direct child: green</li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</div>
```

- http://jsfiddle.net/9YkDx/

However, two things to note about your example code:

1. Although `classname > ul` looks more specific than `classname ul`, it’s not, so your second rule will override your first (although because both rules have the same effect, it’s difficult to tell.
2. Although you probably know this, to actually select a class name, you want `.classname`, not `classname`.

Answer (score 2):

`classname > ul` - select first level ul children of classname

`classname  ul` - select all ul children of classname

Comment: Using `children` to describe the descendant combinator and `first level children` for child combinator causes the kind of confusion faced by the OP. There is only one level of children any lower level is descendants.

Comment: @Vladimir: true, but not actually answering what the OP is asking.